# focus on opened window without allowing another window to open not working on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This function works in chrome but not working in IE. 
       I am trying to avoid opening multiple windows when click multiply time. 
       I want it to find the existing opened window and use that.

```js
function newWindow() {
  var tab;
  tab = window.open('http://google.com', 'MyTab', 'height=800px,width=1500px,resizable=yes');
  tab.focus();
}
```

```html
<body>
  force to open tab in same window
  <a href="#" onclick="newWindow();">New Window</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears, that IE throws an "Access denied" error when trying to re-open `tab` (due to the cross-origin content, but why, it is not clear). This stops the script, and `tab.focus()` is never executed.

To fix the problem, move the definition of `tab` to the outer scope, and wrap  `window.open(...)` to a `try..catch`, like so:

```
var tab;
function newWindow() {
    try {
    tab = window.open('http://google.com', 'MyTab', 'height=800px,width=1500px,resizable=yes');
  } catch (err) {;}
  if (tab) {
     tab.focus();
  }
}
```

This way you can store the original `tab` and `tab.focus()` will bring it in front of the main wind on the screen.

Comment: Its not throwing error in IE but is still opening multiple windows instead of using the current opened window.

Comment: @EmilolaOsinowo I got "Access denied" error when I ran your code at JSFiddle. When I added the error handling as above, everyhing works fine in IE too. The key is the second argument, which is the name of the newly-created window, and if it is the same every time opening a window, browsers should open an existing window instead of a new-one. IE is not an exception, the feature has been supported in IEs for ages.

Comment: There's an option, though, which might override this behavior. Open "Internet options" and on "General" tab, click "Tabs" button, there you can find some options how pop-ups should be handled. (The text might be different in the button, I don't have english version of IE at hands right now.)

Comment: Thanks @Teemu Its still not working yet on IE. let me try out something.